# Using Kong in spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, kong

How to implement KONG gate-way  in spring cloud architecture? 
I am new to KONG technology and I want to implement it in my springcloud architecture . I couldnt find any documentation on its implementation in spring cloud architecture . Can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation about Kong anywhere in the spring cloud documentation since it is not part of spring cloud.

Comment: is it possible to use kong in springcloud ?.... can it be used over zuul ?

Comment: It's an api gateway, it can be used in front of anything. There's no special integration.

Comment: thank you @spencergibb .... do you have any idea related to its implementation in spring cloud ?

Comment: I've never used kong, so no I do not.